# How to get specific type instance (not object type) by reflection in c#

Tags: c#, reflection

I tried to know the way to get a specific type instance by reflection.
there ware many ways to get object type instance by reflection.
but, my conclusion is there is no way to get a specific type instance by reflection.

I tried to do it like this

I made a function that returns the specific typed instance. and I called it by reflection. but It still returns object type instance. the function I made is
like this. so simple.

```
public class MTT
{
    public MTT GetModel()
    {
        return new MTT();
    }
}
```

So, I didn't want to, but I made the function like this.

```
 if (headerOrder == 1)
     parsedModel.MSH = (MSH)header;
 else if (headerOrder == 2)
     parsedModel.FAC = (FAC)header;
 else if (headerOrder == 3)
     parsedModel.PRD = (PRD)header;
 else if (headerOrder == 4)
     parsedModel.PID = (PID)header;
```

Please let me know if there is the way to get a specific type instance by reflection.

Thank you.

---- Add ----

this is my code to make instance

```
var headerType = Type.GetType(_headerNamespace + value);
header = Activator.CreateInstance(headerType);
```

here is a problem. 'header' is the object type. 
So, I wanted to make this to specific type instance.
but I don't know the smart way.
There was only way I can do is to make many if and else phase.

please give me the wisdom you have. It will help me.

Thank you.

Comment: The *variable*, `header` is of type `object` but the object it's referencing is of a specific type. How would you have it be otherwise? What type would *you* give to the variable called `header`? This almost always happens with reflection - the reflection code can only give you `object` references. It's up to you with superior knowledge of what you've just done to tell the compiler what the real type is (via a cast) and assign it to a compatible location - you've already got that code.

Comment: Are you just trying to avoid the cast? The (MSH), (FAC), (PRD), (PID) casts?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. There is a string, it have many values that split by '/' character (example "HeaderType/123/Company/Name/....) . It will be parsed. I want to make a instance by string "HeaderType" and use it like this [ParsedModel.MSH = header] not using many if and else phase. If there is a smart way to cast object to specific instance.

Comment: Yes. I want to avoid the cast with many if and else phase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very, very slightly less verbose than what you've already got:

```
    public static void SetIfSameType<K>(ref K toSet, object val)
        where K : class
    {
        if (val.GetType() == typeof(K))
            toSet = val as K;
    }

    SetIfSameType(ref parsedModel.MSH, header);
    SetIfSameType(ref parsedModel.FAC, header);
    SetIfSameType(ref parsedModel.PRD, header);
    SetIfSameType(ref parsedModel.PID, header);
```

Comment: Works fine so long as `MSH`, etc., are the actual classes and not base types of hierarchies.